# java jssc modem send msg

Tags: java, jssc

I am trying to send text messages from Java/Netbeans using a cell modem based on the [SIM900](https://kuns-design.world.taobao.com/chip). Using TeraTerm, I verify that I can send messages using the modem with basic AT commands. The following code attempts to use `jssc` to send messages.
I do not get errors and the data appears to be written to the modem, but I never receive a text message.  For the phone number, I have tried both with an `+`, and without.
In TeraTerm, the number must be without the `+` to work. Many variations have been tried, and many `.println`'s used.  Still not making progress.
I hope someone can see the error of my ways.

Thanks in advance. Doug

```
package jssc_test;

import jssc.SerialPort; 
import jssc.SerialPortException;
import jssc.SerialPortList;

public class Jssc_test {

    public static SerialPort serialPort=null;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        try {
            String[] portNames = SerialPortList.getPortNames();
            for(int i = 0; i < portNames.length; i++){
                System.out.println(portNames[i]);
            }

            if(portNames.length < 1){
                System.out.println("No ports available");
                System.exit(0);
            }
            else{
                serialPort = new SerialPort(portNames[0]);
            }
            System.out.println("Port opened: " + serialPort.openPort());
            System.out.println("Params set: " + serialPort.setParams(9600, 8, 1, 0));
            System.out.println("\"Hello World!!!\" successfully writen to port: " + serialPort.writeBytes("Hello World!!!".getBytes()));

            serialPort.writeBytes(" AT+CMGF=1".getBytes());
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            System.out.println("bytes back = " + serialPort.readString());
            serialPort.writeBytes(" AT+CMGS=\"585*******\"".getBytes()); // \r = <CR>.  Tried both with and without '+'.  In TeraTerm, only works without +.  error if use: \r\n
            //Thread.sleep(1000);
            //System.out.println("bytes back = " + serialPort.readString());
            //serialPort.writeBytes("0x0D".getBytes()); // send <CR>
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            System.out.println("bytes back = " + serialPort.readString());
            serialPort.writeBytes("THIS IS A TEST from DS.".getBytes()); // placing Cntr-Z string in text did not work:  \u001A
            //serialPort.writeBytes("0x0D".getBytes()); // send <CR>
            serialPort.writeBytes("0x1A".getBytes()); // send <ctrl>Z
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            System.out.println("bytes back = " + serialPort.readString());

            System.out.println("Port closed: " + serialPort.closePort());
        }
        catch (SerialPortException ex){
            System.out.println(ex);
        }
    } // ******************* end main ***************

} // *********************** end main class ***********************
```

Answer (score 1):

I was able to answer the question I posed above.  Below code works.  The event listener does not need to be in there.  The major changes that helped are defining the new line and end of file as bytes "public static final Byte eof = 0x1A, nl=0x0D;" then writing the bytes to the serialPort separately from the commands "serialPort.writeByte(nl);".  I hope this helps others.

Doug

PS: I wrote a java class that may simplify sending code to the SIM900 using jssc, if anyone is interested.

```
    package jssc_test;

//import jssc.SerialPort; 
//import jssc.SerialPortException;
//import jssc.SerialPortList;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import jssc.*;
import static jssc.SerialPort.PURGE_RXCLEAR;
import static jssc.SerialPort.PURGE_TXCLEAR;
import static jssc_test.Jssc_test.serialPort;
/**
 *
 * @author DStockman
 */
public class Jssc_test {

    public static SerialPort serialPort=null;
    public static final Byte eof = 0x1A, nl=0x0D;
    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        //SerialPort serialPort = null;
    try {
        String[] portNames = SerialPortList.getPortNames();
    for(int i = 0; i < portNames.length; i++){
        System.out.println(portNames[i]);
    }

        if(portNames.length < 1){
            System.out.println("No ports available");
            System.exit(0);
        }
        else{
            serialPort = new SerialPort(portNames[0]);
        }
        System.out.println("Port opened: " + serialPort.openPort());
        System.out.println("Params set: " + serialPort.setParams(9600, 8, 1, 0));

        serialPort.writeBytes("ATI".getBytes()); // get modem ID
        serialPort.writeByte(nl);
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        System.out.println("modem ID = " + serialPort.getEventsMask());

        /*
        int mask = SerialPort.MASK_RXCHAR + SerialPort.MASK_CTS + SerialPort.MASK_DSR;//Prepare mask
        serialPort.setEventsMask(mask);//Set mask
        try{
            serialPort.addEventListener(new SerialPortReader());//Add SerialPortEventListener
        }
        catch (SerialPortException ex) {
            System.out.println(ex);
        }
        */

        // just looking up settings
        System.out.println("events mask = " + serialPort.getEventsMask());
        System.out.println("flow control mode = " + serialPort.getFlowControlMode());
        System.out.println("output buffer bytes = " + serialPort.getOutputBufferBytesCount());
        //serialPort.purgePort(PURGE_RXCLEAR | PURGE_TXCLEAR);

        serialPort.writeBytes(" AT+CMGF=1".getBytes());
        serialPort.writeByte(nl);
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        System.out.println("bytes back set modem to text mode = " + serialPort.readString());
        System.out.println("Success entering number: " + serialPort.writeBytes(" AT+CMGS=\"5857738696\";".getBytes())); // \r = <CR>.  Tried both with and without '+'.  In TeraTerm, only works without +.  error if use: \r\n
        serialPort.writeByte(nl);
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        System.out.println("bytes back after number entered = " + serialPort.readString());
        serialPort.writeBytes("THIS IS A third TEST from DS 09/29/16.2.".getBytes()); 
        serialPort.writeByte(nl);
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        serialPort.writeByte(eof);
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        System.out.println("bytes back = " + serialPort.readString());
        Thread.sleep(10000);
        //serialPort.purgePort(SerialPort.PURGE_TXCLEAR);

        //attempt to get msgs received by modem
        serialPort.writeBytes("AT+CMGL=\"ALL\"".getBytes()); 
        serialPort.writeByte(nl);
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        System.out.println("bytes back = " + serialPort.readString());

        System.out.println("Port closed: " + serialPort.closePort());
    }
    catch (SerialPortException ex){
        System.out.println(ex);
    }
    } // ******************* end main ***************

} // *********************** end main class ***********************


class SerialPortReader implements SerialPortEventListener {

    public void serialEvent(SerialPortEvent event) {
        if(event.isRXCHAR()){//If data is available
            if(event.getEventValue() == 1){//Check bytes count in the input buffer
                //Read data, if 10 bytes available 
                try {
                    System.out.println("bytes back inside listener = " + serialPort.readString());
                    byte buffer[] = Jssc_test.serialPort.readBytes(10);
                    System.out.println("listener text:");
                    System.out.print(Arrays.toString(buffer));
                    System.out.println("End listener text:");
                }
                catch (SerialPortException ex) {
                    System.out.println(ex);
                }
            }
        }
        else if(event.isCTS()){//If CTS line has changed state
            if(event.getEventValue() == 1){//If line is ON
                System.out.println("CTS - ON");
            }
            else {
                System.out.println("CTS - OFF");
            }
        }
        else if(event.isDSR()){///If DSR line has changed state
            if(event.getEventValue() == 1){//If line is ON
                System.out.println("DSR - ON");
            }
            else {
                System.out.println("DSR - OFF");
            }
        }
    }
}
```